# What is the smallest Finite Field in which the following polynomial is factorizable to irreducible factors?

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

What is the smallest Finite Field in which the following polynomial is factorizable to irreducible factors?

> $$(x^2+x+1)(x^5+x^4+1)(x^7+x^6+x^3+1) $$

Comment: Irreducible depends on the field you choose. For example, the factor $\;x^2+x+1\;$ is irreducible over $\;\Bbb Q\;$ or over $\;\Bbb R\;$ , but reducible over $\;\Bbb C\;$ or over $\;\Bbb F_3:=\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\;$ ...

Comment: I stated the smallest 'Finite' Field, e.g. $\mathbb{GF}(q)$. Is there ambiguity then?

Comment: Oh, I missed that "finite" think. I shall dwell on it, yet the rest of my comment remains: if the three factors above are *already* irreducible over some finite field then you're done, say. "Irreducible" depends on the field.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks. Obviously on $\mathbb{GF}(2)$ and $\mathbb{GF}(3)$ it is reducible.

Comment: Well, on $\;\Bbb F_2\;$ the last factor is reducible but not the first two, and on $\;\Bbb F_3\;$ the three factors are reducible...

Comment: so the question is actually: what is the smallest finite field in which the given factors are irreducible?

Comment: Please clarify. Did you intend to ask for the smallest field where the given factorization is a factorization into irreducibles? If so, then Dietrich's observation about the last factor settles it. But, taking your question literally, any polynomial is factorizable to a product of irreducible factors over any field, in which case the answer is $GF(2)$.

Answer (score 2):

There is no finite field in which all given three polynomials are irreducible. The last
polynomial, i.e., $x^7+x^6+x^3+1$ has always $-1$ as a root, hence is reducible over all finite fields. 
On the other hand, $\mathbb{F}_3$ is the smallest finite field, in which all three polynomials are reducible: $x^2+x+1=(x+2)^2$, $x^5+x^4+1=(x^3 + 2x + 1)(x + 2)^2$, and
$x^7+x^6+x^3+1=(x^6 + x^2 + 2x + 1)(x + 1)$.